# docker run, unable to load .bashrc in non -it

Tags: linux, bash, docker

When I run `docker run --rm example:latest env` I see that `.bashrc` is not loaded?

```
❯ docker run --rm example:latest env
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=2b8bd52f95dd
LANG=C.UTF-8
GPG_KEY=...
PYTHON_VERSION=3.10.7
PYTHON_PIP_VERSION=22.2.2
PYTHON_SETUPTOOLS_VERSION=63.2.0
PYTHON_GET_PIP_URL=...
PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256=...
HOME=/root
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10

RUN echo "export TEST=123" >> /root/.bashrc
```

If I do run `docker run --rm -it example:latest bash`, I see that TEST is loaded.

```
❯ docker run --rm -it example:latest bash
root@1b3e5473bda4:/# env
HOSTNAME=1b3e5473bda4
PYTHON_VERSION=3.10.7
PWD=/
PYTHON_SETUPTOOLS_VERSION=63.2.0
HOME=/root
LANG=C.UTF-8
GPG_KEY=...
TERM=xterm
SHLVL=1
PYTHON_PIP_VERSION=22.2.2
PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256=...
PYTHON_GET_PIP_URL=...
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
TEST=123
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Here's the code form the .bashrc that I need to be able to run.

```
#AWSume alias to source the AWSume script
alias awsume="source awsume"
```

What might I be missing so that when I run a non `-it` I can load .bashrc contents properly such as sourced scripts?

Comment: Most paths to running Docker containers don't read `.bashrc` or shell dotfiles at all.  Use the Dockerfile `ENV` directive instead.

Comment: What do you mean by "unable"? What is the content of `.bashrc`? Where are you "loading" `.bashrc`?

Comment: @KamilCuk I'm sure of how Docker behaves with .bashrc so what you see is what's present in terms of loading it or not.

Comment: @DavidMaze ENV is not an option I think as the container needs several commands which need to be sourced at a later stage from the .bashrc. What would you do if you need to source several commands/scripts which will be used by python later when running the container?

Comment: `Docker behaves with .bashrc` docker ignores bashrc, it's just a file. `I see that TEST is loaded.` Yes, this command line _is_ running bash (irrelevant of docker) and _bash_ loads bashrc. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html . It's the same when doing `ssh`.

Answer (score 0):

> a non -it I can load .bashrc contents properly such as sourced scripts?

"Load" it yourself.

```
docker .... bash -c '. ~/.bashrc && "$@"' _ your command line
```

Or add a similar script to docker entrypoint.